# Bringing content from other pages without refreshing the entire page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I wrote my first AJAX script that brings content from other pages without refreshing the entire page.  I just want to see if improvements can be added to it, or if I'm doing something not recommended.

```
$(function(){
    // content container content loader
    $("#nav-tabs-list a").click(function() {
        var page = this.hash.substr(1);
        //$("#sidebar-content-container").html(""); // displays content only after fully loaded
        $.get("content/" + page + ".php", function(gotHtml) {
            $("#content-container").html(gotHtml);
        });
    });
    if ( location.hash ) {
        $("a[href="+location.hash+"]").click();
    } else {
        $("#nav-tabs-list a").click();
    }

    // sidebar content loader
    $("#sidebar-container #sidebar-tabs-container a").click(function() {
        var page = this.hash.substr(1);
        //$("#sidebar-content-container").html(""); // displays content only after fully loaded
        $.get("content/sidebar-content/" + page + ".php", function(gotHtml) {
            $("#sidebar-content-container").html(gotHtml);
        });
    });
    if ( location.hash ) {
        $("a[href="+location.hash+"]").click();
    } else {
        $("#sidebar-container #sidebar-tabs-container a").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: I assume this is jQuery? What javascript library are you using?

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have some copy pasted code there.

How about

```
function enableLinks( selector , path , container )
{
  /* Allow ajax to work */
  $( selector ).click( function()
  {
    var page = this.hash.substr(1);
    $.get( path + page + ".php", function( html ) 
    {
      $( container ).html( html );
    });    
  });
  /* Allow bookmarks to work */
  if ( location.hash )
    $("a[href="+location.hash+"]").click();
  else
    $(selector).click();
}

$(function()
{
  enableLinks( "#nav-tabs-list a" , "content/" , "#content-container" );
  enableLinks( "#sidebar-container #sidebar-tabs-container a" , 
               "content/sidebar-content/" ,
               "#sidebar-content-container" );
});
```

The things you do with `location.hash` are a bit of a mystery to me.

Comment: @tomdenmuyt Your code seems the simplest and works. But when i try to navigate to a specific page it does not work for example http://localhost/TEMPLATE/#features in my code i go to the features page yet i cant in yours. How do i fix that?

Comment: @JarolinVargas Try now